# Android.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.SearchView(Not in Action Bar)

Tags: android

When i use a `SearchView` inside a Layout action bar.Then i got error like:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
```

Answer (score 6):

Easy, you have written v7 the code layout but you casting as v4 version. Because of you got this error.

Use the code to import in java file **`import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;`** instead of **`import android.widget.SearchView;`**

Please refer this link:
http://javapapers.com/android/android-searchview-action-bar-tutorial/

Comment: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'`
if you need to install v7 support.